# Save as dialog not showing

Tags: python, google-app-engine, http, webapp2

I'd like to show a save as dialog for a file download through a HTTPHandler (GET) in a Google App Engine application (Webapp2).

Although I am using the attachment content disposition like:

```
   self.response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
   self.response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename='test.xls'"
```

The file is automatically downloaded and the save-as dialog not shown

Comment: I believe it is nothing to do with your code. It is the users browser setting.

Comment: So what happens know in response to a GET?  Can you show the rest of the code for your handler?